# Writing a GCD of three numbers as a linear combination

Tags: abstract-algebra, algorithms, divisibility

i know how to find the $\gcd(5,11,2^{2015}-1)$. but i can't seem to find the linear combination. do you find it the same way we find the linear combination of two integers.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
$$\gcd(a,b,c) = \gcd(\gcd(a,b), c)$$

Comment: how would i use that?

Comment: @user230463 You calculate the gcd for two of the numbers. Then take the gcd of the result and the next number. And so on.

Comment: i know how find the gcd, but what i can't find is the linear combination

Comment: @user230463 But if you know how to do it for two numbers, this should be all you need - we're only taking two numbers at a time. There's a lot more substitutions to be made, but the process is identical.

Comment: what do you mean by taking two numbers at a time?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ (a,b)\mid c\,\Rightarrow\, (a,b,c) = (a,b) = ja + kb = ja + kb + 0c$

Comment: i get 3 equations and i need to solve for the variables, is that right

Comment: Do you know how to compute $\,j,k\,$ in the Bezout identity $\,1 = (5,11) = 5j+11k?\, $ If so, then you are done by the above.

Comment: yeah, its 1 = -2*j+ 1*k

Comment: what about 1=(5,11,20)?

Comment: You need to compute the $\,j,k\,$ that yield said Bezout identity for $\,(5,11).\ \ $

Comment: can you please explain, what you mean by that?

Comment: @user230463 You need to find integers $\,j,k\,$ such that $\,1 = \gcd(5,11) = 5j + 11k.\,$ Then you can apply the above hint with $\,a,b,c = 5,11,\ldots$

Comment: sorry, but i can't understand what your trying to say/]?

Comment: Did you find the solutions for $\,j,k?\ \ $

Comment: yes, its (-2,1)